# ExtJS scope between listerners

Tags: extjs

I'm calling controller functions twice from my view. For some reason, one of the calls is working while the other is not. I'm relatively new to ExtJS so help would be appreciated.

```
    Ext.define('Gsm.view.systemmessages.SystemMessages', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    ...
    ...
    ...
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'searchfield',
            cls: 'searchfield',
            listeners: {                
                change: function(field, value){
                    this.getController().filterStore(value); <-- can not reach controller from here
                }
            }
        }]
    }],

    columns: [{
        text: 'Tipas',
        width: 150,
        dataIndex: 'type',
        sortable: true
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
    {   
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }],

    listeners: {
        select: function(RowModel, record, index, eOpts){
            this.getController().onRowClick(record); <-- can reach controller from here
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: sharing your controller code would be helpful

Comment: But controller has nothing to do with it does it? I mean I cant even call controller, I get "this.getController() is null" with dockItem listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have your listeners be a string which should resolve onto the ViewController automatically?

```
listeners : {
    select : 'someSelectName'
}

listeners : {                
    change : 'someChangeName'
}
```

Then in your ViewController, in those methods above then do the onRowClick and filterStore method calls. Basically moving the logic from the view into the ViewController.

```
someSelectName : function(RowModel, record) {
    this.onRowClick(record);
},

someChangeName : function(field, value) {
    this.filterStore(value);
}
```

Comment: This is great, not only did you solve my problem, you improved my code.

Comment: A nice little compliment! Thank you!